# Javascript :: Grid/List View from XML

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display an XML file that contains "Cat Food" data, element by element in a Grid/List View (just like an e-commerce site).
I use the first example from "w3schools.com" site:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_list_grid_view.asp

Problem is after the XML file is opened and parsed I get this console error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.parseXML".

I put the links to all necessary files:

1. Cats.php file (which is an .html - didn't had time to rename it)
   https://webhostsites.000webhostapp.com/Cats.php
2. Dein Bestes.xml (this file can be downloaded and opened later via "Choose File" from the Cats.php)
   https://webhostsites.000webhostapp.com/Dein%20Bestes.xml
3. CSS file (this is used mainly for the Grid/List View)
   https://webhostsites.000webhostapp.com/mystyle.css

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because you try to pass on 16th node from XML , though there are 15 of them.
What to do to exclude this error:
in function parseXML change do/while to be  while (i < noItems-1) (instead of while (i < noItems))

Answer (score 0):

Thx, 
So it was about looping, thought was some weird javascript specific error.

Your solution doesn't work though because it misses the last element.